# Regex to reject sequence of Digits

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I need to validate phone number. Below is the code snippet

```
-(BOOL) validatePhone:(NSString*) phoneString
{

      NSString *regExPattern = @"^[6-9]\\d{9}$"; ORIGINAL
//    NSString *regExPattern = @"^[6-9](\\d)(?!\1+$)\\d*$";
      NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
      NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:phoneString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneString length])];
      NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)regExMatches);
     if (regExMatches == 0) {
        return NO;
     }
     else
        return YES;
}
```

I want to reject phone number that is in sequnce example
9999999999, 6666677777

Comment: Did you mean to match a number that does not have the same digits at a stretch? Try [`@"^[6-9](?!\\d*(\\d)\\1)\\d{9}$"`](https://regex101.com/r/l8GKJH/1)

Comment: Note you may quantify the backreference to only disallow numbers with a specific amount of consecutive repeated digits, say, [`^[6-9](?!\d*(\d)\1{2})\d{9}$`](https://regex101.com/r/NC0EuJ/1) will only reject numbers with 3 identical consecutive digits.

Comment: Oh nice. Quantifiers and Negative lookaheads. I modified it to accept atleast 4 consecutive digits. `^[6-9](?!\d*(\d)\1{4})\d{9}$` . Hope this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to disallow 5 and more identical consecutive digits.

Use

```
@"^[6-9](?!\\d*(\\d)\\1{4})\\d{9}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NC0EuJ/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[6-9]` - a digit from `6` to `9`
- `(?!\d*(\d)\1{4})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
  - `(\d)` - a digit captured into Group 1
  - `\1{4}` - the same digit as captured in Group 1 repeated four times
- `\d{9}` - any 9 digits
- `$` - end of string (replace with `\z` to match the very end of string do disallow the match before the final LF symbol in the string).

Note that `\d` is Unicode aware in the ICU regex library, thus it might be safer to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: hi, do you have any references where i can learn creating regex. Video tutorials will be better.

Comment: @LeXeR I do not know any regex teaching videos. I suggest that you do the basic exercises at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com). You will get the grasp of regex basics and will be able to handle such issues by yourself. [Lesson 10](http://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end) will be very helpful.